# Disable QuickEditMode in 64 bit

Tags: c#, .net, windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I currently use the following code in the old 32bit architecture windows:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetConsoleMode", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint mode);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetConsoleMode", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hSystemMenu, bool bRevert);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr RemoveMenu(IntPtr hSystemMenu, uint nPosition, uint wFlags);
```

This is the code, which uses the GetConsoleMode and SetConsoleMode:

```
if (!GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out consoleMode))
                throw new IOException("Console setup error - failed to retrieve current ConsoleMode");
consoleMode &= ~Constants.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE;
Constants.SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode)
```

I know, try to get the application running within a 64bit machine, but I get this error:

```
Type: System.IO.IOException
Message: Console setup error - failed to retrieve current ConsoleMode
```

I googled and checked that the dll on the 64-bit windows is also named kernel32.dll.. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `GetConsoleMode`?

Comment: @Iridium sure, I added the code in the original post, please have a look

Comment: And where do you get `consoleHandle`?

Comment: @Iridium IntPtr consoleHandle = new IntPtr(3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to assume that the console handle always has a value of 0x3, especially as there's a Windows API method to retrieve the standard handles.

The following seems to work for me when running as both a 32bit and 64bit executable (on 64bit Windows), and appears to be how .NET does it internally:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

var consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(-10); // STD_INPUT_HANDLE
GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out var mode);
```

Comment: thanks that works for me.. one more question to that: I also have a IntPtr invalidHandle = new IntPtr(-1);.. I should also use the GetStdHandle function. is there the int value still -1?

Comment: Reasonably sure that Windows defines -1 as the invalid handle, so that’s ok to leave as-is. `GetStdHandle` is only used to retrieve the input/output/error handles.